# iPhone SDK System Provided Buttons and Icons

Tags: ios, button, icons, uikit, iphone-sdk-documentation

Where can the System-Provided Buttons and Icons mentioned in the following link to the iPhone Developer Human Interface Guidelines be found in the SDK?  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/SystemProvided/SystemProvided.html

I expected them to show up in Interface Builder somewhere, but I haven't been able to locate them.

Comment: Please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13967410/662096

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading that link pointed me to [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20100801105643/http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/EditingNibFileObjects/EditingNibFileObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH12-SW71)¹, which under the appearance heading (as directed) I found the following quote:

> In addition to custom buttons, you can configure bar button items using several standard images and titles. When a bar button item is selected, the Identifier field of the Attributes inspector lists the type of the button. Choosing a type other than Custom lets you create buttons representing standard system actions.

---

¹ The [original resource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/EditingNibFileObjects/EditingNibFileObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH12-SW19) has been 302ed by Apple since this answer was written, thus the link to an archived copy.

Answer (score 6):

Apple has moved the link again, for iOS 7.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/index.html