# Where to find iPhone system buttons and icons graphics?

Tags: iphone, graphics, system, icons, button

I'm trying to find a way to use the original Apple system buttons and icons in a web site.
Is there a way to get these original graphics in png format?

There are not-so-nice ways to obtain them of course. Two I was thinking of:

1. Save them from [this link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/SystemProvided/SystemProvided.html), then convert to png.
2. Take screen captures on the iPhone itself, and cut the icons from the saved images.

Is anyone aware of a nicer way to obtain the original graphics? Does anyone know where they are stored on the Mac?

Thanks :-)
Ariel

Comment: Do you really think that’s a good idea, copyright-wise?

Answer (score 5):

You can download this [UIKIT ARTWORK EXTRACTOR](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) project from github and try run it on any simulator , it will extract the all icons of the current SDK and save it to your desktop with all icons.

Source :
 https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor
Apple HIG Issue:
 https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor/issues/11

As per the above issue, The extracted appropriate icons can be used in your iphone apps but using it in other platform may cause any copyright issue.

Answer (score 1):

The icons are scatter throughout the system applications they are a part of. There is no central location they can be harvested from. Some of the icon apps might be useful for harvesting them once you find them.

If your interested in UI elements, the Interface Builder bundles have most of them inside.

I know that [Graffeltopia](http://graffletopia.com/) has numerous Omnigraffel stencils with Mac system graphics in them.

I think copyright wise, your okay as long as (1) you put a notice that that Apple has the copyright on the images and (2) you don't create the impression you are in anyway Apple Computer and (3) you don't use them to create close simulations of the Apple user interface in any medium.

Otherwise, it follows under fair use. For example, if your doing and article on the Apple UI you can definitely use the graphics in examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I actually think I haven't clarified enough. I'm specifically looking for button and icon graphics used on the iPhone, in order to use them in a web site that will be browsed with iPhones.
Just as an example, the icon represented by UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera.
Do you know where I can find these, and do you think there's any copyright issue doing what I described?

Thanks!
Ariel

Comment: Oh, I miss read. Yes, you can get the UI elements. I've got an entire folder of them but I can't remember where I got them. I believe they're lifted out of the simulator. However, I can say rather firmly that creating an actual web site that looks like the iPhone interface will get you immediately sued. Apple has done so in the past over exactly that use. You can only use the graphics for an actual interface in actual iPhone apps html based or otherwise.

Comment: I'll see if I can remember how I got them. Check back in a day or two.

Comment: jqtouch has been around for quite a long time, and it is still there to create UI that looks like real iPhone apps. How come you get sued for that?
http://www.jqtouch.com/

Comment: jqtouch lets you make iPhone apps that run on the iPhone. He's talking about making a standalone web site that will be browsed in safari. I'm pretty certain that using actual copyrighted Apple graphics to make a 3rd party website is grounds for a lawsuit.