# System-Provided Buttons in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I would like to use the playback button in iPod coverflow view.

Are all the system provided icons on this page? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/SystemProvided/SystemProvided.html

or is there a more detailed list?

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13967410/662096

Answer (score 0):

Those are all the provided system icons. There's no other list.